# Does the Visual Studio 2010/11 Beta Portable Class Library Project support INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mvvm, visual-studio-2012, portable-class-library

When creating a Portable Class Library in either Visual Studio 2010, or Visual Studio 11 Beta is INotifyPropertyChanged supported? If so which namespace can it be found in?

Or is it supported only in the Visual Studio 11 Beta?

You can download it for Visual Studio 2010 SP1 here:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b0e0b5e9-e138-410b-ad10-00cb3caf4981/

I've seen people say you can use it online, but any MSDN documentation i've seen doesn't mention INotifyPropertyChanged, but does mention things such as INotifyCollectionChanged being supported.

The reason i'm wondering if there are two different implementations of this project type is that I know with .NET 4.5 beta you can target Metro style apps, which you can't do from VS2010 and .NET 4

Comment: If only there was a way to search for [this interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)

Comment: I know how to find the interface via MSDN. Is it supported in a Portal Class Library project? Is the entirety of System.dll supported in this type of project?

Comment: One of your first questions was "which namespace can it be found in?". The answer is on that page. The interface defines one method, and according to the icons next to it, it's supported in PCL, and at the bottom of the page it says "supported in: Portable Class Library". Once those facts are established, I can't get much more out of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeremy Likness wrote a nice series of three articles exploring the topic of making a portable library for MVVM XAML apps across the different platforms (Silverlight, WPF and Metro-style).

- [Part 1: Creating the Portable
  Library](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2012/03/understanding-portable-library-by.html)
- [Part 2: Portability in Silverlight and WPF: a Tale of Type Forwarders](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2012/03/understanding-portable-library-by_09.html)
- [Part 3: Portability in Metro: A CLR and WinRT Love Affair](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2012/03/understanding-portable-library-by_14.html)

This series primarily focuses on the ICommand interface, but the problems are similar.

To answer your other question, the Metro-style version of this interface is defined in the [Windows.UI.Xaml.Data namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br209917.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Currently only VS 11 Beta supports INotifyPropertyChanged (unless targeting only SL + Phone), however, we'll be soon releasing an update to our VS2010 tools which will include the same support for .NET 4.5, Phone 7.x, SL & Metro.